# Serilog doesn't log to Azure App Insights when deployed to an App Service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, serilog

I have a .Net Framework API and I am using Serilog with the Application Insights sink for logging.

I have configured Serilog with the AppInsights instrumentation key and using ILogger to trigger logging. When I run my API locally the log message show up in my App Insights Transaction search. However, when I deploy the API to an Azure App Service, the logs seem to never make it to App Insights.

I have tried updating the sink to latest, making sure the Instrumentation Key is correct but nothing seems to help.

My logging config:

```
var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, new TraceTelemetryConverter());
Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
```

Then I'm using the following to test logging:

```
Log.Logger.Error("Log.Logger LogTest: Error");
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After deploying the Application make sure you have enabled the Application Insights tab in Azure webapp.

[image]

To Log the message, use the below format

```cs
 Log.Information("Log message Home");
```

```cs
  var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights("YourInstrumentationKey", new TraceTelemetryConverter());
   Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
```

***MyAPIController***

```cs
   private readonly ILogger<HelpController> _logger;
    public HelpController(ILogger<HelpController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Log.Information("Log message Help Controller");
        }
```

***Output:***
[image]

- You can also check the traces in `ApplicationInsights` = > `Transaction search`
  [image]

[image]

Comment: So annoyingly clicking that button made it work but I don't know why that's the case? Before clicking it, it said "Application Insights is linked through Instrumentation Key in app settings" so I assumed it was linked properly. Do you know what clicking that button does?

Comment: Initially we have integrated Application Insights for Local, so you can see the logs/ traces in locally even without deploying. For deployed WebApp to track App Insights you need to Enable Application Insights in Portal.